# Mobx @observable is not work if its init value is undefined in react-native 0.59

Tags: react-native, observable, mobx, mobx-react

I'm migrating react-native 0.51.1 to 0.59.8. And I'm facing a problem of Mobx.

If an @observable decorated member have assigned init value like this

```js
@observable cnt = 0;
```

then it works.

But if it's undefined,

```js
@observable cnt;
```

then it doesn't work.

I have many undefined observable stores and they worked in 0.51.0.
I want to make it work as undefined.

Babel decorate options have been changed during migration.

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true}],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { 'loose': true}],
  ],
}
```

```js
//This doesn't work but worked in react-native 0.51.0
import { observable } from 'mobx';

export class Count {
  @observable cnt;

  constructor(initValue = 0) {
    this.cnt = initValue;
  }

  add(){
    this.cnt++;
  }
}
```

```js
//This works
import { observable } from 'mobx';

export class Count {
  @observable cnt = 0;

  constructor(initValue = 0) {
    this.cnt = initValue;
  }

  add(){
    this.cnt++;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that in the latest version of `mobX`, undefined is not a valid observable anymore: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/api/observable.ts#L80. It only seems to accept strings, objects, arrays, sets and maps.

Comment: @MarcelKalveram ..umm nope. I installed mobx@^4.2.0, and mobx-react@^5.0.0. These were using on react-native@0.51.0 and it worked. But @0.59.8, it doesn't work. The `createObservable ` code is almost same with mobx4-master https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/mobx4-master/src/api/observable.ts

Comment: I solved this declaring `undefined` explicitly. 
`@observable cnt = undefined;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this declaring `undefined` explicitly.

```js
@observable cnt = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using Babel with Typescript. The culprit was these babel plugins:

```
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
```

It appears that decorators on uninitialised class properties do not get called with these plugins. It's possible they are interfering with Typescripts's handling the class properties.

My babel.config.js now looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }]],
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']
};
```